# Read image file from database and view it in html tag <img>

Tags: jquery, python, html, image, postgresql

I retrieve an image from postgres database using ,,the  image column is binary column so i need to convert this image to applicable path to view it in image tag `<img>` the problem that when i try to retrieve the image i got something like that

```
P1o7A+iH9aUg4P8AwEUAHG45/vKPyoHJB6csentTiTuz6vSAkhT7Mf1xQAg+UZ7BKc2NxHoVFN6Kf90U4j5j67xQAg5OR/ezSLxtzwME05ecY9WNN/h5/ufzoAX
```

but i want it as a path to view it in the html tag

i could pass this image database value to JQuery too so i need to know if it's applicable to be done with any of both.

any help ?

Thanks

Comment: This sort of question has often been asked here. This is a woefully inefficient way of serving image files. The proper way is to simply save the link to the image in the database and store the files somewhere else. Also makes your code much much simpler.

Comment: this is not good solution because it's web APP in the cloud so i need the users to upload their profile pictures ,, that can't be completed using your soluation

Comment: And why do images need to be uploaded into the database for a 'web app in the cloud'?

Comment: the web app and the database is in the cloud ,,, think of it like u r using fb :)

Comment: lol and do you think FB stores images in the database??

Comment: i think so ? what do u think ?

Comment: I think it's time for you to do a bit of research

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use data URLs
If using image tag use this:

```
<img width="16" height="16" alt="star" src="data:image/gif;base64,<image code goes here>" />
```

eg. if it's an PNG image

```
<img width="32" height="32" title="" alt="" src="data:image/png;base64,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" />
```

general format

```
data:[<mime type>][;charset=<charset>][;base64],<encoded data>
```

You can also use it in CSS

```
 background:
 url(data:image/gif;base64,<put encoded data here>)
 url(data:image/png;base64,<put encoded data here>)
 url(data:image/jpg;base64,<put encoded data here>)

 For any type of image
 url(data:image/<put image type here>;base64,<put encoded data here>)
```

Note : to use this you need first base64 encode your image and then store in the database

```
<?php

$a=file_get_contents('image.jpg');
$enc=base64_encode($a);
//store $enc in the table
?>
```

Comment: sry but it doesn't work and also what if the ick is not gif ?